# Parsing nested JSON objects

Tags: objective-c, json

Right now I'm learning how to get data from the web using JSON. I want to get an image for each of my posts (from a Rails app). Following the Treehouse Library tutorial I would have to do something like this:

**TableViewController.m**

```
self.upcomingReleases = [NSMutableArray array];

NSArray *upcomingReleasesArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_releases"];

for (NSDictionary *upcomingReleaseDictionary in upcomingReleasesArray) {
    UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [UpcomingRelease upcomingReleaseWithReleaseName:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_name"]];
    upcomingRelease.thumbnail = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    upcomingRelease.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"url"]];
    [self.upcomingReleases addObject:upcomingRelease];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [self.upcomingReleases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:upcomingRelease.thumbnailURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    cell.imageView.image = image;
    cell.textLabel.text = upcomingRelease.release_name;

    return cell;
}
```

**UpcomingRelease.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *release_name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *thumbnail;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;

//Designated Initializer
- (id) initWithReleaseName:(NSString *)release_name;
+ (id) upcomingReleaseWithReleaseName:(NSString *)release_name;

- (NSURL *) thumbnailURL;
- (NSString *) formattedDate;

@end
```

**UpcomingRelease.m**

```
- (NSURL *) thumbnailURL {
    return [NSURL URLWithString:self.thumbnail];
}
```

I'm supposed to replace all the "thumbnail" with my own string. The problem is that my images are inside a nested object and there's more than 1. I want to call the URL of the thumb from the first image_file in each of my posts. How can I do this?

Thanks.

**My JSON API**

```
upcoming_releases: [
{
  id: 2,
  release_name: "Nike Lebron X Low",
  release_price: "165",
  release_colorway: "Raspberry-Red/Blueprint-Court",
  release_date: "2013-09-07T00:00:00.000Z",
  url: "http://obscure-lake-7450.herokuapp.com/upcoming/2",
  images: [
    {
      image_file: {
        image_file: {
          url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/soleresource/uploads/releases/nike-lebron-x-low-raspberry.jpg",
          thumb: {
            url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/soleresource/uploads/releases/thumb_nike-lebron-x-low-raspberry.jpg"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      image_file: {
        image_file: {
          url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/soleresource/uploads/releases/nike-lebron-x-low-raspberry-2.jpg",
          thumb: {
            url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/soleresource/uploads/releases/thumb_nike-lebron-x-low-raspberry-2.jpg"
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show the code you have so far for parsing the JSON and extracting that data you need.

Comment: I just updated my question.

Comment: Please go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  In particular note the thing called an "array".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can rely on the structure of the JSON feed, after converting it into a foundation object (`NSArray` in this case):

```
NSString *fileURL;
NSString *thumbURL;
if (jsonArray.count) {
   NSDictionary *firstRelease = jsonArray[0];
   NSArray *images = firstRelease[@"images"];
   if (images.count) {
      NSDictionary *firstImage = images[0][@"image_file"];
      fileURL = firstImage[@"image_file"];
      thumbURL = firstImage[@"thumb"];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) to help parse the data. For example, to get the data from URL, then parse it into an `NSDictionary`, you can do this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]];
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *response = [parser objectWithData:jsonData];
```

For a good, working example on how to do this, check out this APP.NET [public stream client](https://github.com/phil-brown/app.net-psc/blob/master/ChaiOne%20Challenge/ViewController.m) for iOS.